# How to use Selector query in ZK

Tags: zk

I was going through these pages on ZK documentation [ID_Space -Selector](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/UI_Composing/ID_Space#Selector) and looked at following code

```java
comp.query("#ok"); //look for a component whose ID's ok in the same ID space
comp.query("window #ok"); 
comp.queryAll("window button");
```

I am wondering how can I use this in my code? I am creating 2 drop downs and adding Id to both these drop downs

```java
Listbox listbox=createListbox(widget, DetailsListRenderer.ORDERSTATUS.class, null,orderStatus);
listbox.setId(ORDER_STATUS_ID);
```

So when My page is getting refreshed, I am getting exception of Unique Id, I was wondering if these is a way I can query component and see if same component with same Id already exists and in case it exists, I should not add ID to that component, or should not create component at all
Any suggestion?

I tried something like

```java
widget.getFellow( ORDER_STATUS_ID); but getting `org.zkoss.zk.ui.ComponentNotFoundException` exception.
```

Answer (score 2):

```java
widget.getFellow("#" + ORDER_STATUS_ID);
```

Answer (score 0):

For widgets that co-exist in the same ID space (a.k.a fellow widgets), one may use any of the following to refernece a fellow from a certain widget:

```js
var fellow = widget.$f('fellowID');
var fellow = widget.$f().fellowID;
var fellow = zk.Widget.$(jq('$fellowID')[0]);
```